# How to implement a Node.js chat app into an existing website?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I've been getting into Node.js recently and I really like the example shown on Socket.io's website showing a real time chat application. However, in all of the examples I see the URL used is localhost:8080 or whatever ip and port is applicable. However, is there any way to implement this into an existing webpage so that it isn't a separate URL? If not, how are these real-time chat apps done in real life?

Comment: Yes, there's no reason why your web page can't connect out to a Socket.IO server somewhere else.  Have you tried it?  Were you running into a specific issue? And if so, can you share the code you're using?

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately, I don't have the code remaining from the tests I've done, but the main issue I had was that I couldn't get my page to receive emit commands from my Node.js server. My main website is working on a Windows IIS server but I wasn't able to get any communication between it and Node.js.

Comment: Why do you need your IIS server to communicate to your Node.js server?  Are you trying to proxy the web socket connection from IIS to Node.js?  (This is possible... will requires some config in IIS.)

Comment: I'm trying to have the Node.js receive an event from the HTML website (like a chat message) and then send another event for the all clients on the HTML website to receive the aforementioned chat message. Maybe I'm thinking of this in completely the wrong fashion but that's what made sense to me.

Comment: @JazzyJake - your IIS server wont have anything to do with your frontend website communicating with node, all it does it send the HTML/Javascript/CSS that gets sent to the end users device. How your frontend website connects to NodeJS is entirely dependent on the UI framework your website is written in. If its a wordpress or squarespace site, you will have to tackle it from that angle.

Comment: Oh good to know! In that case, what is the framework for IIS? I'm sorry if this a dumb question but I'm trying to get my head wrapped around the different frameworks and protocols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these sort of questions are usually not meant for stackoverflow, but everyone has been where you are! Stackoverflow is dedicated for code related questions, but this might help you get to your next steps:

NodeJS is a backend server language, you will have to deploy it to a production environment.

New developers typically learn by using services like heroku.com to quickly host backend apps, they take a lot of the complexity of learning Linux or Microrost Server out of the mix, but they are not typically used by more advanced developers.

More advanced (real world apps) run on AWS/Azure/Other hosts.

Implementing it in an existing website requires both frontend and backend languages. Nodejs gives you a leg up in that it's javascript, and can run in both frontend and backend situations.

There are many places online that provide tutorials for creating backend servers and frontend websites.

the list is endless, but some good places for new developers are

https://frontendmasters.com/

https://teamtreehouse.com/

https://egghead.io/

Here is a tutorial on heroku for setting up a nodejs app
[Getting Started on Heroku with Node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs)